# Spring @Scheduled with fixedDelay=0

Tags: java, spring, schedule

I have a method that I'd like to invoke over and over from the start of my application, but I do not want to have a delay in between the end time of the method execution and the start of the new one. Basically doing `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=0)` will technically do the job, but spring does not allow 0 millisecond for the delay.

Comment: You're overthinking this. `while (true) { doThing(); }`

Comment: the reason i want to use @Scheduled is because I don't want to invoke the method myself. I want spring to do it.

Comment: Nevermind, @PostConstruct will do. ur right im overthingking this

Comment: If you do it from PostConstruct, be careful not to block the thread. Push it to an executor or a dedicated thread

Comment: Can you explain the use case? I'm thinking you might have a problem that shouldn't be solved like this.

Answer (score -2):

If zero is not permitted, what about `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=1)` ? 1 millisecond